# Ошибка Invalid object name Books

Tags: c#, asp.net

Выходит вот такая ошибка: Invalid object name Books. Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
        public SqlDataReader Selectsql()
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader reader;

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Books";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

        sqlConnection1.Open();

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        return reader;
    }
```

Comment: Значит в базе данных, а которой вы подключаетесь, нет таблицы с именем `Books`. Поскольку вы указали только сетевой адрес к СУБД и не указали саму БД через `InitialCatalog`, то запрос выполняется на базе с именем `master`. Не думаю, что вы создавали таблицы в этой служебной БД.

Comment: Это как? Куда вставить?

Comment: В строку соединения добавьте имя своей базы данных и убедитесь, что все таблицы в ней есть: `@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=ИмяВашейБазыДанных"`